# VBA If Statement to pull Data from another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am having an issue. I am trying to pull Data from one workbook to another. I have successfully done this, however I need to pull the information If coulmn C of work book 1 matches coulmn A of Workbook 2 and if coulmn D of workbook 1 matches coulmn B of workbook 2. Then pull Coulmn B from workbook 1 to coulmn D of workbook 2. I am on windows 10 with Excel 2016. Any help is appreciated

This is the Code now.

```
    Sub AmandaTest()
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If vFile = "" Then Exit Sub
'Set targetworkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
'Set Sheets for both Source & Target Workbooks
Set wsS = wbTarget.Sheets("MainPage")
Set wsT = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
'get the last row with data from both Sheets into variables
LastRowT = wsS.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowS = wsT.Cells(wsS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'For instance, copy data from a range in the first workbook to another range in the other workbook
For i = 1 To LastRowT 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet Target
    For x = 1 To LastRowS 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet Source
        If wsT.Range("C" & i).Value = wsS.Range("C" & x).Value Then
        'if value from Column C in Target equals any value from Column C in Source then
            If wsT.Range("B" & i).Value = wsS.Range("D" & x).Value Then
            'if value from Column B in Target equals value from Column D on Sheet Source then
                wsT.Range("D" & i).Value = wsS.Range("B" & x).Value 'pass values into Target Sheet
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: you can't compare two columns using `Range("C").Value = Range("C")` you would have to loop through rows to see if they match then transfer data, what about if there is an extra row in one of the columns, then the columns are not equal?

Comment: Okay, Do you have an example of that with the code I've put in above? Also, the issue is I can't compare the values at all. The first If statement throws an error.

Comment: Are you sure there is a sheet named Sheet1 in both wb and wb2?

Comment: Yes I am sure they both have a sheet named sheet1

Comment: Xabier is right, there is no such Range as `Range("C")` and it is the direct cause of this error. Range for column C is 
 `Columns("C").EntireColumn`, but in general you want to detect last row with data and then check everything up to this point. You should read on how to use loops to compare data.

Comment: Or, just `Columns("C")`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code will help you figure out how to do what you are wanting to achieve, I've used a double loop to go from Row 1 to Last on Target Worksheet to compare against values in Source Sheet and then pass values as required:

```
Sub AmandaTest()
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If vFile = "" Then Exit Sub
'Set targetworkbook
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
'Set Sheets for both Source & Target Workbooks
Set wsS = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsT = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")
'get the last row with data from both Sheets into variables
LastRowT = wsT.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowS = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'For instance, copy data from a range in the first workbook to another range in the other workbook
For i = 1 To LastRowT 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet Target
    For x = 1 To LastRowS 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet Source
        If wsT.Range("C" & i).Value = wsS.Range("C" & x).Value And wsT.Range("B" & i).Value = wsS.Range("D" & x).Value Then
        'if C = C and B = D then
                wsT.Range("D" & i).Value = wsS.Range("B" & x).Value 'pass values into Target Sheet
        End If
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help, but when I try this code it throws the error   "subscript out of range"   and goes straight for the source   Information.                                                                                                                                                                                                          Set wsS = wbSource.Sheets("Data")

Comment: @Stacie, does the Sheet "Data" exist in the Workbook with the code?

Comment: I changed it to fit the code, just so that it wouldn't be so confusing. The code threw an error before that and I didn't know if that would stop it.

Comment: @Stacie, I've tried the code above and it worked for me, can you elaborate as to what error you are getting?

Comment: I finally got it to run through, but it just isn't pulling the data now. I realized that the code up there is opposite of what I was trying to accomplish so I swithced everything.

Comment: It isn't pulling the data? Does that mean that there is no occurrence where C from Target matches C from Source And B from Target matches D from Source..?

Answer (score 0):

```
 This is the code that works, if you notice the original code had coulmn "C" on it, but this has coulmn "A". That's because I was checking the wrong row. Thank you so much for your help @Xabier


   Sub AmandaTest()
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If vFile = "" Then Exit Sub
'Set targetworkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
'Set Sheets for both Source & Target Workbooks
Set wsS = wbTarget.Sheets("MainPage")
Set wsT = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
'get the last row with data from both Sheets into variables
LastRowS = wsS.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowT = wsT.Cells(wsS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'For instance, copy data from a range in the first workbook to another range in the other workbook
For i = 1 To LastRowS 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet Target
    For x = 1 To LastRowT 'loop from row 1 to last on Sheet Source
        If wsS.Range("A" & i).Value = wsT.Range("C" & x).Value Then
        'if value from Column C in Target equals any value from Column C in Source then
            If wsS.Range("B" & i).Value = wsT.Range("D" & x).Value Then
            'if value from Column B in Target equals value from Column D on Sheet Source then
                wsS.Range("D" & i).Value = wsT.Range("B" & x).Value 'pass values into Target Sheet
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

End Sub